# How to route traffic through multiple servers for faster connection

Tags: vpn, internet, proxy, download, speed

Internet “speed” is not only dependent on what your ISP gives you but what servers give you, and the latter is independent of your ISP, so no matter how much you pay for Internet, some sites (most) won’t improve a whole lot. The only time I can really see the potential of the connection is when downloading a (perfectly legal) torrent with large files and large amounts of seeders, such as say a copy of Ubuntu, servers have more bandwidth than what they give you, they just save it for other users.

What I want to know is how to use multiple proxies to access the server from different points at the same time, therefore getting more overall speed, and then break up the data and feed it all back the the main connection (I’m probably not explaining this too good, but someone might understand what I’m getting at). Preferably something that would work with all protocols not just web browsing but also third party apps and gaming etc…

Comment: Please don't simultaneously lecture us on how (you assert) the web works and ask for help.   (While some of your statements are correct, others are false)

Answer (score 2):

You can't - the web does not work the way you want it to - specifically

- Neither UDP nor TCP offer inbuilt mechanisms for splitting up
  traffic, making a generic solution unrealistic
- ISP's usually use ingress and egress filters to prevent routing of
  IP addresses not sourced/targetted through their network - to prevent
  certain types of attacks. (making a generic solution unrealistic)
- The speed of your connection is controlled by a number of factors other
  then the speed of your connection - including the latency of the connection
  and the amount of packet loss.
- Most servers will try and share loads fairly, but will not leave bandwidth
  sitting idle - they will, however, prioritise bandwidth.
- A proxy defines a source and destination IP address - multiple proxies will
  have different source addresses so the target will handle them as different
  sessions (correctly)

Answer (score 1):

That is not a really a viable approach from a client-side perspective. I don't believe there are any technologies that support the technique you describe.

First, for downloads, HTTP/FTP downloads are a single binary response stream, so the data you are downloading comes as the result of a single request. If the server supports PARTIAL CONTENT (206) then you may be able to arrange a system where you establish several downloads with calculated offset and length, to do it over multiple connections, but it would not work for every server. Either way, at the very least, the mechanism would have to know it is manipulating a HTTP connection, so it would only work for HTTP data.

Second, most modern websites aren't just static documents anymore, and are programmatically constructed server-side, so they often rely on the concept of a Session. Sessions are generally limited to a user connection, so if you connect from two different locations, those are two different sessions. Attempting to compose and render a page made from Gets that came from different sessions will be almost impossible, because each session has its own cookies, scripts, etc, and there are security barriers at play designed to keep attackers from doing the kind of things you are thinking of.

Ultimately, such a tool could exist, but it would have to have a great deal of protocol intelligence (so it could rewrite protocol-specific data to use differant connections via differant pathways), and would be limited in its capacity to shunt isolated GETs to other connections, because of the limitations imposed by server-side protocols and operations.